# LINQ to SQL Association 1 to N

Tags: linq-to-sql

How i can change this data mapping, if table UsersInRoles is relational table. (Example for, userId = 3, returns 5 rows).

```
private EntityRef<UserInRoles> roles;
[Association(Storage = "UsersInRoles", ThisKey = "UserId")]
public UserInRoles Roles
{
    get { return this.roles.Entity; }
    set { this.roles.Entity = value; }
}
```

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an EntitySet instead of an EntityRef.

```
private EntitySet<UserInRoles> _roles;

[Association(Storage="_roles", ThisKey="UserId", OtherKey="UserId")]
public EntitySet<UserInRoles> Roles
{
  get
  {
    return this._roles;
  }
  set
  {
    this._roles.Assign(value);
  }
}
```